# How to generate a Singly Linked List from a number's digits?

Tags: python, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have defined a class to make a linked list as follows:

```
class ListNode(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None
```

Now, I've generated a number "sum" and wrote the following code to generate the Linked List: (assuming that sum could possibly have 3 or 4 digits)

```
if len(str(sum)) == 4:
    l3 = ListNode(str(sum)[3])
    l3.next = ListNode(str(sum)[2])
    l3.next.next = ListNode(str(sum)[1])
    l3.next.next.next = ListNode(str(sum)[0])
elif len(str(sum)) == 3:
    l3 = ListNode(str(sum)[2])
    l3.next = ListNode(str(sum)[1])
    l3.next.next = ListNode(str(sum)[0])
```

Is there a way to generate the above using the length of the number "sum" without hard-coding as above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
s = str(975)

start_node = node = ListNode(s[-1])  # initialize to last character in s
for c in reversed(s[:-1]):
    node.next = ListNode(c)
    node = node.next
```

`start_node` should now contain the first node; from there you could `.next` to the next node. `node` always points to the current node in the loop (and could be discarded after the loop).

note that [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) is a built-in function and therefore not a good variable name...

the output of the code above:

```
print(start_node.val)             # 5
print(start_node.next.val)        # 7
print(start_node.next.next.val)   # 9
print(start_node.next.next.next)  # None
```

---

you could even write the code above more compact (but way less readable imo):

```
start_node = node = ListNode(s[-1])
for c in reversed(s[:-1]):
    node.next = node = ListNode(c)
```

Comment: I'll change the variable name "sum". The solution works! Thanks